# Convert tuple to list

Tags: c#, .net, list, tuples

I need to convert different tuples to lists of strings.

How can i convert a tuple that contains different types to a list of strings in C#?

And of curse i need a generic solution for different tuples.

**Example:**

I want to convert this tuple to a list: ("word", 1, 's', US)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# ValueTuple of any size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413583/c-sharp-valuetuple-of-any-size)

Comment: I suppose you could use reflection to enumerate the values of the tuple and cast them.

Does this help? https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/365/accessing-tuples-at-runtime-using-reflection

Answer (score 3):

Linq solution:

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

 ...

 public static List<string> TupleToList(ITuple value) {
   if (null == value)
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

   return Enumerable
     .Range(0, value.Length)
     .Select(i => value[i]?.ToString()) // ?. - don't call ToString() on null
     .ToList();
 }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pwYrf5)

Comment: i can't use the ITuple interface because it's inaccessible due to protection level

Comment: @Alon Ehrenlieb:Sorry, it seems that you should add `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`; I've provided fiddle as well

Comment: it didn't work for me. I have also tried to install the nugget.

Comment: @AlonEhrenlieb Which .NET and C# version are you using?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski .NET 4.7, and C# version is automatically selected based on .NET version

Comment: `ITuple` is available from .Net 4.7.1 onwards: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple

Answer (score 0):

Modified from Kobi Hari's answer from [C# ValueTuple of any size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413583/c-sharp-valuetuple-of-any-size)

I added some LINQ to convert each element to a string before returning to fit the question requirements.

```
public List<string> TupleToStringList(ITuple tuple)
{
  var result = new List<object>(tuple.Length);
  for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
  {
    result.Add(tuple[i]);
  }
  return result.Select(obj => obj.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Or using the original method and converting to strings as a separate step

```
public List<object> TupleToString(ITuple tuple)
{
  var result = new List<object>(tuple.Length);
  for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
  {
    result.Add(tuple[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

// your code
{
    ...
    List<object> objectList = TupleToString(tupleToConvert);
    List<string> stringList = objectList.Select(obj => obj.ToString());
}
```

Comment: i can't use the ITuple interface because it's inaccessible due to protection level. And i added using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = null;

            var t = ("word", 1, 's', "US");
            foreach (var item in TupleToList(t))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        private static List<string> TupleToList(ITuple tuple)
        {
            var result = new List<string>(tuple.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
            {
                result.Add(tuple[i].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The `TupleToList` takes a [ITuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple) as parameter and returns list of string. Goes without saying, there could be issues based on what the tuple contains which you might need to handle.

Comment: I think it's not working for me because apparently i'm using ValueTuple and not Tuple, can you provide me the solution for valueTuple? Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Answer (score 0):

Use Value Tuple

var result = return (type1, type2, type3);

```
return new ModelDto()
            {
                Model1= result.Item1,
                Model2= result.Item2,
                Model3= result.Item3
            };
```