# C# - How to use Select LINQ method using properties from a dynamically list of properties

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose we have a simple class called `Person` with properties as `FirstName, LastName, Age`.

Now I have a list of properties as a list of strings.

```
var props = new List<string> { "FirstName", "Age"}.
```

Now I have a `List` of `Person` objects.

```
var persons = new List<Person> {....}
```

How to use `Select` LINQ method to get just the Person properties that appear in the `props`?

```
var result = persons.Select(p => code here)
```

The result should be a list of anonymous objects, where an anonymous object should contain the properties from `props` list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use a `Where` instead of a `Select`.

Comment: Show us the exact input and output you expect. This question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: @DavidG, the output should be a list of anonymous objects. Every anonymous object should have the properties from `props` list.

Comment: No, give us an ACTUAL example of input and output. What is `Person`? What is the exact output? Note you can't create anonymous type on the fly. And even if you could, how would you expect to use them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select - does it answer your question? Take a look for `Nick Butler's` answer, seems it very similar for your question

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut post the *actual* code. Anonymous types can't be returned from a method so whatever you read must be used in the method itself. Why use a list of property names in that case instead of an actual anonymous type expression? `.Select(x=>new {x.Name,x.Surname,....})`. If you really want a dynamic `select` you'll have to build that `Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>>` by yourself. It's doable, but better to not have to do this. If you want to query a database - why use LINQ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. It was tested in Visual Studio and works properly

```
var props = new List<string> { "FirstName", "Age" };

var persons = new List<Person> { 
                  new Person { FirstName = "FirstName1", LastName = "FirstName1", Age=10},
                  new Person { FirstName = "FirstName2", LastName = "FirstName2", Age=20},
                  new Person { FirstName = "FirstName3", LastName = "FirstName3", Age=30}
    
    };

    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);
    var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

    List<JObject> list = new List<JObject>();

    foreach (var item in jArray)
    {
        JObject jsonObj = new JObject();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            foreach (JProperty jprop in item)
            {
                if (jprop.Name == prop)
                    jsonObj.Add(jprop);
            }
        }

        list.Add(jsonObj);
    }

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonList);
```

to use it you can convert to dictionary for example

```
var dictArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>[]>(json);
```

or list of tuples or key-value pairs

```
List<(string,object)> values = dictArray.SelectMany(i=>i).Select(i =>(i.Key,i.Value)).ToList();
```

output

```
    FirstName   FirstName1
    Age         10
    FirstName   FirstName2
    Age         20
    FirstName   FirstName3
    Age         30
```

or you can convert to dynamic object

```
dynamic eo = dictArray.Select( e=> e.Aggregate(new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>,
                                (a, p) => { a.Add(p.Key, p.Value); return a; })).ToList();
```

test

```
var firstName = eo[1].FirstName; //FirstName2
```

class

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> personProps = typeof(Person).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);

List<string> props = new List<string> { "FirstName", "Age"};

IEnumerable<string> selectedProps = props.Where(p => personProps.Contains(p));
```

Comment: i have updated my question to be more clearly.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut what kind of object do you want as end-result? If you only want to select specific properties there must be some sort of list that holds these?

Comment: I can have a simple anonoymous object

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut now I can understand what you want. I will try to bring a solution to this but honestly, I don't think there's a simple answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly you want to kind of trim your Person object.
If that's correct I'd recommend to create an instance method inside your Person class that gives you the opportunity to create an unnamed object or Tuple (for example like here: [C# ValueTuple of any size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413583/c-sharp-valuetuple-of-any-size)) directly from your Person instanciated object. You just need to pass your props List for matching the properties (like here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string)) then and just use this very method inside your Select statement.